# How can I insert a if function in an array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have an array

$data_array =

```
array
    (
        "limit" => $limit,
        "page_number" => $page,
        "books" => $books
    );
```

I want that if $books is set then the array should be

```
array
    (
        "limit" => $limit,
        "page_number" => $page,
        "books" => $books
    );
```

and if the variable $books is not set the array should be

```
array
(
    "limit" => $limit,
    "page_number" => $page
);
```

please can anybody help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use

```
$data_array = array
(
    "limit" => $limit,
    "page_number" => $page
);

if(isset($books)){
    $data_array['books'] = $books;
}
```

Comment: i would do this.. cause code takes lesser lines and is easier for maintenance

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($books))
{
    $data_array=array
    (
        "limit" => $limit,
        "page_number" => $page,
        "books" => $books
    );
}
else
{
    $data_array=array
    (
        "limit" => $limit,
        "page_number" => $page
    );
}
```

Comment: if I have a long array of values and variable it is very difficult to use if 5 or 6 time for a long arrary

Answer (score 1):

```
        array
        (
            "limit" => $limit,
            "page_number" => $page,
        );
        if ($books is set) 
           array['books'] = $books;
```

I thinks this should do the job.